# How to send 2 json array via ajax to view in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm using ajax to passing json array to view in django. My index page divided into 2 columns left and right, each column have some text input and I have a button 'Save' to save all value of text input both left side and right side into db. I created 2 json array to store value of 2 columns then passing them via ajax. But in view.py recieved only one json array.

This is my code ajax and code in view.py:

```
var jsonArrLeft = [];
var jsonArrRight = [];
$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
    $('.form-group right').each(function () {
        debugger;
        value = $(this).find("input[name='ValueRight']").val()
        label = $(this).find("input[name='LabelRight']").val()
        jsonArrRight.push({
            label: label,
            value: value
        })
        var jsonRight = JSON.stringify(jsonArrRight);
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'add_label_value' %}',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                'jsonRight ': jsonRight 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
     $('.form-group left').each(function () {
        debugger;
        value = $(this).find("input[name='ValueLeft']").val()
        label = $(this).find("input[name='LabelLeft']").val()
        jsonArr.push({
            label: label,
            value: value
        })
        var jsonLeft = JSON.stringify(jsonArrLeft);
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'add_label_value' %}',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                'jsonLeft ': jsonLeft 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })

})
```

This is my view.py code:

```
def add_label_value(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
try:
    if request.is_ajax():
        order_header = OrderHeader()
            jsonRight = json.loads(request.POST.get('jsonRight'))
            for x in jsonRight:
                order_header.label = x.label
                order_header.value = x.value
                order_header.position = 'right'
                order_header.save()
           jsonLeft = json.loads(request.POST.get('jsonLeft'))
            for y in jsonLeft:
                order_header.label = y.label
                order_header.value = y.value
                order_header.position = 'left'
                order_header.save()
except OSError as e:
    error = messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, e, extra_tags='add_label_value')
    html = '<p>This is not ajax</p>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Its because you're firing two requests instead of one, send this `{jsonRight:jsonRight, jsonLeft:jsonLeft}` in a single post request.

Answer (score 1):

Please include both situations in One ajax post request and send it to your view.The mistake you are doing here is that you are sending two different requests.

```
    var jsonArrLeft = [];
    var jsonArrRight = [];
    $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
        $('.form-group right').each(function () {
            debugger;
            value = $(this).find("input[name='ValueRight']").val()
            label = $(this).find("input[name='LabelRight']").val()
            jsonArrRight.push({
                label: label,
                value: value
            })
        $('.form-group left').each(function () {
            value = $(this).find("input[name='ValueLeft']").val()
            label = $(this).find("input[name='LabelLeft']").val()
            jsonArr.push({
              label: label,
              value: value
           })
            var   jsonLeft = JSON.stringify(jsonArrLeft);
            var jsonRight = JSON.stringify(jsonArrRight);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'add_label_value' %}',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken':  $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                    'jsonRight ': jsonRight ,
                    'jsonLeft': jsonLeft      


},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: A proper answer includes an explanation...not just code. Without an explanation the answer is of little value for anyone to know what you have done and how it helps OP's situation